# Turning a SQL row into an array

Tags: php, mysqli

**PROBLEM**
I have a set of data that is being output by selecting each dataset and utputting them row by row.

**QUESTION**
Is there a method of fetching this data and storing it as an array that I am then able to out turn into set of string values?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM respondent_data WHERE respondent_firstname = 'John'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $categoriesTest[] =   $row["respondent_sdo"];
    $row["respondent_dcto"];
    $row["respondent_ed"];
    $row["respondent_ca"];
    $row["respondent_dhpt"];
    $row["respondent_irt"];
    $row["respondent_gl"];
    $row["respondent_il"];      

      // Turn my output into an array ready to be used for the JSON string

  }

}
```

**EXAMPLE**

So each of those values outputs an integer from the column rows I need them to be turned into an array like: 2,4,3,5....

Comment: What should be the desired output here ?

Comment: there is no such thing as a "comma seperated array". but if you instead want to create a comma-separated string: try *implode()*. if you instead want to create an array from your results, think of this: *$row* already is an array.

Comment: @Maximus2012 so I just need those rows to output into an array so I can use it as a dataset for my chart itll be turned into a JSON formatted datastring

Comment: What happens if you try to `json_encode()` `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want specific associative properties from all columns queried from the MySQL call, just set them in an array with their respective properties:

```
$categoriesTest = array();
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM `respondent_data` WHERE `respondent_firstname` = 'John'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $categoriesTest[] = array(
        'respondent_sdo'    => $row['respondent_sdo'],
        'respondent_dcto'   => $row['respondent_dcto'],
        'respondent_ed'     => $row['respondent_ed'],
        'respondent_ca'     => $row['respondent_ca'],
        'respondent_dhpt'   => $row['respondent_dhpt'],
        'respondent_irt'    => $row['respondent_irt'],
        'respondent_gl'     => $row['respondent_gl'],
        'respondent_il'     => $row['respondent_il']
    );
}
$categoriesTest = json_encode($categoriesTest); // get JSON
```

However, if you wanted to keep all columns queried, but create custom elements you'll want to use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$categoriesTest = array();
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM `respondent_data` WHERE `respondent_firstname` = 'John'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $categoriesTest[] = array_merge($row, array(
        'custom_value_1'    => 'test',
        'custom_value_2'    => 'test2'
    ));
}
$categoriesTest = json_encode($categoriesTest); // get JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM respondent_data WHERE respondent_firstname = 'John'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  $i=0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $categoriesTest[$i]["respondent_sdo"] = $row["respondent_sdo"];
    $categoriesTest[$i]["respondent_dcto"] = $row["respondent_dcto"];
    $categoriesTest[$i]["respondent_ed"] = $row["respondent_ed"];
    $categoriesTest[$i]["respondent_ca"] = $row["respondent_ca"];
    $categoriesTest[$i]["respondent_dhpt"] = $row["respondent_dhpt"];
    $categoriesTest[$i]["respondent_irt"] = $row["respondent_irt"];
    $categoriesTest[$i]["respondent_gl"] = $row["respondent_gl"];
    $categoriesTest[$i]["respondent_il"] = $row["respondent_il"];      

    $i++;

  }

  var_dump($categoriesTest);

}
```

Comment: @AneesSaban yep ;) but if we do not need array keys, why not to use mysqli_fetch_row?

Comment: You know that $categoriesTest[] = $row; will keep the array keys, right? I otherwise don't get your point. :P

Comment: @VictorRudkov that does not make any sense. `$row` already has the keys, and it does not *lose* them when you assign the *whole array* to a different variable.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann My bad. I doesn't mean without keys at all, I mean without creating associative user-friendly keys. I always think about any tiny performance boosts I could make. Imo mysqli_fetch_row would work a little bit faster than mysqli_fetch_assoc because it has not to do anything with keys (they are just incrementing integers). Maybe it would also use less RAM. But it is just a suggestion.